# Show messages on lock screen on Galaxy S3

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-s-3, lock-screens

Is it possible to show previews of messages (as the iPhone does) on the lock screen on a Galaxy S3 running android 4.1.2?

Answer (score 1):

There is a settings on text Messaging App to Preview Messages on Lock Screen.

Go to `Text Messaging App` --> (press menu) `Settings`-->(go to Notification Settings) Check `Preview Messages` Option.

Or

You can use [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.activenotifications). It will display new messages when phone is locked.

Comment: Yes I already have that option enabled, it only shows the number of unread messages but no preview.

Comment: its default behavior.
If you wish to show messages you can use an app(look at answer). It will display Message in lock screen.